# How use julia package "Mathematica"?

Tags: julia

I added the Mathematica package (https://github.com/JuliaInterop/Mathematica.jl) to julia 1.3.1.

Now if I use command...

```
using Mathematica
```

I get this error:

```
[ Info: Precompiling Mathematica [32681abc-2ee8-5d23-a06a-fe3af83833d6]
┌ Warning: Package Mathematica does not have MathLink in its dependencies:
│ - If you have Mathematica checked out for development and have
│   added MathLink as a dependency but haven't updated your primary
│   environment's manifest file, try `Pkg.resolve()`.
│ - Otherwise you may need to report an issue with Mathematica
└ Loading MathLink into Mathematica from project dependency, future warnings for Mathematica are suppressed.
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: @mmimport not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
 [2] eval at ./boot.jl:330 [inlined]
 [3] top-level scope at /Users/murray/.julia/packages/Mathematica/W4UIg/src/Mathematica.jl:36
 [4] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [5] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1105
 [6] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [7] top-level scope at none:2
 [8] eval at ./boot.jl:330 [inlined]
 [9] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:425
 [10] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /Users/murray/.julia/packages/Mathematica/W4UIg/src/Mathematica.jl:36
in expression starting at /Users/murray/.julia/packages/Mathematica/W4UIg/src/Mathematica.jl:34
ERROR: Failed to precompile Mathematica [32681abc-2ee8-5d23-a06a-fe3af83833d6] to /Users/murray/.julia/compiled/v1.3/Mathematica/cqgUM_XJ2Lx.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1283
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1024
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:922
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:917
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: The package is super old and unmaintained for at least 3 years. I doubt that you can get it to work without overhauling the code.

Comment: You may be interested in the [SymPy.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPy/SymPy.jl) package that provides many similar features in the domain of symbolic computation and it is well documented.

Comment: For Mathematica, use [MathLink.jl](https://github.com/JuliaInterop/MathLink.jl) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Chris’s comment, the suggestion is to use MathLink.jl. I talked to the package maintainer for Mathematica and added to deprecation warning to the readme as to avoid future issues.